# difference between instantiation of classes in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, instance

I am learning oops concepts in python and developing a small CLI based game from zed shaw's learn python the hard way but got confused in the instantiation of an object.

Code:

```
  class animal(object):
        scenes = {
            'cat': Cat(),
            'dog': Dog(),
            'milk': Milk(),
            'fight': Fight(),
            'timeout': Timeout(),}

        def __init__(self, start_scene):
            self.start_scene = start_scene

        def next_scene(self, scene_name):
            return Map.scenes.get(scene_name)

        def opening_scene(self):
            return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)


    foo = animal('cat')
    game = run(foo)
    game.play()
```

**can someone explain what is the difference between below instantiations?**

`foo = animal()` and `foo = animal('cat')`

Now i understand `foo = animal()` is setting `foo` to an instance of class `animal` and can access methods from class `animal` like `foo.opening_scene()`

What does `foo = animal('cat')` do?

Comment: 'cat' is passed in as the parameter **start_scene**.

Answer (score 1):

When you call animal(), it creates an instance with a default construct. When you call animal('cat'), you actually call **init**(self, start_scene) to create your instance. What it then does is set the attribute start_scene to 'cat'.